# unknown command "manifest" for "istioctl"

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I am trying to install on my kubernetes cluster with version 1.3.7 and I’ve got the following error message:

```
istioctl manifest apply                    
Error: unknown command "manifest" for "istioctl"
Run 'istioctl --help' for usage.
```

The verify shows:

```
istioctl verify-install

Checking the cluster to make sure it is ready for Istio installation...

#1. Kubernetes-api
-----------------------
Can initialize the Kubernetes client.
Can query the Kubernetes API Server.

#2. Kubernetes-version
-----------------------
Istio is compatible with Kubernetes: v1.16.6.

#3. Istio-existence
-----------------------
Istio will be installed in the istio-system namespace.

#4. Kubernetes-setup
-----------------------
Can create necessary Kubernetes configurations: Namespace,ClusterRole,ClusterRoleBinding,CustomResourceDefinition,Role,ServiceAccount,Service,Deployments,ConfigMap. 

#5. Sidecar-Injector
-----------------------
This Kubernetes cluster supports automatic sidecar injection. To enable automatic sidecar injection see https://istio.io/docs/setup/kubernetes/additional-setup/sidecar-injection/#deploying-an-app

-----------------------
Install Pre-Check passed! The cluster is ready for Istio installation.
Everything is fine, it should work.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

This command is experimental in 1.3 so use `istioctl x manifest apply`

Comment: where can I find the installation guide for istio for K8s?

Comment: This here https://istio.io/docs/setup/getting-started/#install does not work. The error message is `unknown command "manifest" for "istioctl"`. Do I have to install with `Helm`?

Comment: which version of Istio you downloaded? It should work for 1.4